# How to say thank you for someone tried but could not help me?

Tags: word-choice

Today someone tried to help me to find something but failed, so I said "thank you anyway" to her in the end.

Is "thank you anyway" appropriate in this situation? And what phrase should I use to politely say thank you to someone who tried to help me but failed?

Comment: Yes, that is a perfectly natural and appropriate thing to say. You can also use *thanks all the same*, which no one has mentioned in the answers yet.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Thanks anyway" is perfectly acceptable. You could also use phrases such as "I appreciate your help," or "thanks for trying." There is no specific phrase I can think of reserved for this scenario, though.

Thanks to @CandiedOrange for suggesting an improvement.

Comment: Feeling to lazy to create a competing answer so I'll simply suggest adding "Thanks for trying" as well.

Comment: Or "Thanks for making the effort", or anything roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with, "**Your effort (was/is) appreciated.**" was/is depending on the relationship temporally to the effort; That being said, the other answers are also good.

Comment: Sounds too pompous to be able to use in everyday life.

Answer (score 3):

Some good responses are: 
 **"Thanks/ thank you anyways/anyway" 

"I appreciated that" 

"Thank you for your time/effort" 

"That was greatly appreciated"** 
 
Basically anything that shows your gratitude for them spending time and effort is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I think "Thank you all the same" can be used in this situation.